# Inflate multi-file zip files in linux

Tags: linux, file-management, compression, zip

I just downloaded some zip files that were splited. (The dreamplug rootfs files to be precise).

They are called

```
rootfs_dreamplug_v10_Aug-28-20128.zip.001
rootfs_dreamplug_v10_Aug-28-20128.zip.002
```

I tried to call `unzip` on both of them, but each presents me with a different error message (`001` says to use the last in a series, `002` says that there is something missing).

I tried opening it with the Archive Manager of my graphical file browser, but that said the zips are broken.

How do I extract a multi-file zip file in linux?

Answer (score 0):

The splitting is in fact done very primitively. There is nothing special about it so that you can in fact just use `cat` to combine them back together. I use a combined file in this example, but you can use pipes to do this all in one step.

```
cat rootfs_dreamplug_v10_Aug-28-20128.zip.001 rootfs_dreamplug_v10_Aug-28-20128.zip.002 > rootfs_dreamplug_v10_Aug-28-20128_combined.zip
unzip rootfs_dreamplug_v10_Aug-28-20128_combined.zip
```

Remember to keep the order correctly. Else your zipfile will be corrupted.